# git log two branches, ignoring others

Tags: git

Consider this example `git` repository.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
rm -rf example
git init example
cd example
echo 0 > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -am "initial commit"
git branch branch1
echo 1 > file.txt
git commit -am "1 (on master)"
git branch branch2
git checkout branch1
echo 2 > file2.txt
git add file2.txt
git commit -m "2 (on branch1)"
git merge --no-edit master
echo 3 > file2.txt
git commit -am "3 (on branch1)"
git checkout master
echo 4 > file.txt
git commit -am "4 (on master)"
git checkout branch1
git merge --no-edit master
echo 5 > file2.txt
git commit -am "5 (on branch1)"
git checkout branch2
echo 6 > file3.txt
git add file3.txt
git commit -m "6 (on branch2)"
git checkout master
git merge --no-edit branch2
git merge --no-edit branch1
```

The script above creates two branches (`branch1` and `branch2`) off of the `master` branch; we merge `master` into `branch1` a couple of times, then finally merge `branch1` back to `master`. Meanwhile, we merge `branch2` back into `master` before `branch1` merges back.

If I `git log --graph --oneline` on master, the result looks complicated.

```
*   4f71184 Merge branch 'branch1'
|\
| * d58e9f0 5 (on branch1)
| *   b19c9b4 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| |\
| * | 212f4d6 3 (on branch1)
| * |   1ac0082 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| |\ \
| * | | 26cf8e0 2 (on branch1)
* | | |   9aaa8c5 Merge branch 'branch2'
|\ \ \ \
| |_|_|/
|/| | |
| * | | 425aead 6 (on branch2)
| | |/
| |/|
* | | 67a7fed 4 (on master)
|/ /
* | 6a56133 1 (on master)
|/
* 0d4f076 initial commit
```

In this example, I'm primarily interested in the merges between `master` and `branch1`; I'm not interested in the commits on other branches that have merged to `master`. In this case, there's only just the one other branch (`branch2`) and it only has one commit in it, so it doesn't mess up the graph too badly, but it gets a lot worse when there are many many more branches in play, but I only want to focus on `master` and `branch1`.

If I use `git log --graph --oneline --first-parent master branch1`, the graph looks *almost* right, observing only the first parents in `master` and `branch1`, but the merge commits have no merge lines drawn on them, even when their second parent appears in the log.

```
* 4f71184 Merge branch 'branch1'
| * d58e9f0 5 (on branch1)
| * b19c9b4 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| * 212f4d6 3 (on branch1)
| * 1ac0082 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| * 26cf8e0 2 (on branch1)
* | 9aaa8c5 Merge branch 'branch2'
* | 67a7fed 4 (on master)
* | 6a56133 1 (on master)
|/
* 0d4f076 initial commit
```

I think what I want looks like this, with the `branch2` commit `425aead` dropped from the log. (Again, it's not much clearer, but if there were many more branches like `branch2` the value would be more obvious.)

```
*   4f71184 Merge branch 'branch1'
|\
| * d58e9f0 5 (on branch1)
| *   b19c9b4 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| |\
| * | 212f4d6 3 (on branch1)
| * |   1ac0082 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| |\ \
| * | | 26cf8e0 2 (on branch1)
* | | |   9aaa8c5 Merge branch 'branch2'
|  \ \ \
|  _|_|/
|/  | |
|   |/
|  /|
* | | 67a7fed 4 (on master)
|/ /
* | 6a56133 1 (on master)
|/
* 0d4f076 initial commit
```

Is there a way to get what I want here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git log --graph` won't do the right thing, but it's pretty easy to use `dot` (aka [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)) to generate the correct graph.

I used the `git-log-dot` script from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42825588/54829):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, sys, re

args = ['git', 'log', '--pretty=format:%x00%H%x01%h%x01%P%x00'] + sys.argv[1:]

rows = subprocess.check_output(args).split('\x00')[1::2]

seen_commits = set([row.split('\x01')[0] for row in rows])

print("digraph G {")
for row in rows:
    columns = row.split('\x01')
    commit = columns[0]
    label = columns[1]
    print('"{}" [label="{}"];'.format(commit, label))
    for parent in columns[2].split(' '):
        if parent == "":
            continue
        if not parent in seen_commits:
            continue
        print('"{}" -> "{}"'.format(commit, parent))
print("}")
```

If you put that file on your `$PATH` as `git-log-dot` and `chmod +x git-log-dot`, `git` will automatically run it if you type `git log-dot`. (It's a legacy holdover from when `git` was distributed as separate scripts, `git-checkout`, `git-reset`, etc.)

You'll also need Graphviz. On macOS I installed it with `brew install graphviz`; on Ubuntu I believe you can install it with `sudo apt-get graphviz`.

Graphing the whole repo still looks kinda confusing:

```
git log-dot | dot -Tpng -o graph.png
```

[image: entire repo]

But graphing just the first parents of `master` and `branch1` looks as clean as a whistle:

```
git log-dot --first-parent master branch1 | dot -Tpng -o graph.png
```

[image: just two key branches]

(In the samples above, I also used -Grankdir=LR to make the graphs horizontal, but the default vertical orientation is pretty good, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't.  The problem stems from the way `git log` combines its commit-selecting process with its graph-drawing process.  Without `--first-parent`, it follows all parents of each merge commit—but *with* `--first-parent`, it *strips out* the other parent(s), so that when it gets to the point of drawing connections between nodes, even though both of the two commits it's drawing have a merge link, the link is *gone* from the internal data structures.

If you could combine `--no-walk` and `--graph` in `git log`, this would do it:

```
git rev-list --first-parent master branch1 |
    git log --no-walk --stdin --decorate --oneline --graph
```

i.e., we'd collect up the nodes to display first (`git rev-list`), then instruct `git log` to re-fetch those particular commit-graph nodes, with full parent information, and sort them into a graph-able form and then graph them.  But you can't:

```
fatal: cannot combine --no-walk with --graph
```

This is in the end a fairly hard problem, although a kind of halfway solution seems likely to be implementable, if you should decide to dig into `git log`'s graph-drawing code.  Essentially, we want to break the logging into two pieces: one `--first-parent` scan to collect nodes, and then a second re-scan that re-walks the graph, re-filling-in the in-core data structures for each commit, throwing out parent links to nodes we have not loaded during the first scan (rather than throwing out all but the first one).  That gives us a modified commit-graph that's suitable for drawing, and we won't even need `rev-list` and `--stdin`.