# git log: show second parent on the left

Tags: git

Consider this example git repository.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
rm -rf example
git init example
cd example
echo 0 > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -am "initial commit"
git branch branch1
echo 1 > file.txt
git commit -am "1 (on master)"
git branch branch2
git checkout branch1
echo 2 > file2.txt
git add file2.txt
git commit -m "2 (on branch1)"
git merge --no-edit master
echo 3 > file2.txt
git commit -am "3 (on branch1)"
git checkout master
echo 4 > file.txt
git commit -am "4 (on master)"
git checkout branch1
git merge --no-edit master
echo 5 > file2.txt
git commit -am "5 (on branch1)"
git checkout master
git merge --no-edit --no-ff branch1
git log --graph --oneline
```

We create a branch `branch1`, merge up to it from the `master` branch a couple of times, and finally merge back to `master`.

`git log --oneline --graph` looks weirdly twisted.

```
*   2c3b97a Merge branch 'branch1'
|\
| * 1d722df 5 (on branch1)
| *   54039b6 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | d80d82c 4 (on master)
| * 2399286 3 (on branch1)
| *   9a0cb38 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 31df841 1 (on master)
| * 5809072 2 (on branch1)
|/
* 08fc7a6 initial commit
```

The graph would be simpler if it looked like this:

```
*   2c3b97a Merge branch 'branch1'
|\
| * 1d722df 5 (on branch1)
| *   54039b6 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
|/|
* | d80d82c 4 (on master)
| * 2399286 3 (on branch1)
| *   9a0cb38 Merge branch 'master' into branch1
|/|
* | 31df841 1 (on master)
| * 5809072 2 (on branch1)
|/
* 08fc7a6 initial commit
```

The reason it doesn't look like that, as I understand it, is that `git log` always prefers to show the "second parent" of each merge commit on the right-hand side, so for each merge commit it has to snake around to the right. (The "second parent" is the branch merging in; the "first parent" is the branch we're merging into.)

1. Is there a way to convince `git log` to generate the simpler graph I'd prefer? There's an [old gist from 2013](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/4221767) proposing fixing this ("Let me specify which branches sink to the left"; there are other interesting ideas there, too), but I see no progress on that.
2. Assuming `git log` can't do it naturally, is there another git commit graphing tool/library I can use to make a graph like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [torek's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42822789/54829) to try `dot` (aka [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)) I wrote this Python script to generate output in the `dot` file format. It generates a graph like this, which looks pretty good to me:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess, sys, re

args = ['git', 'log', '--pretty=format:%x00%H%x01%h%x01%P%x00'] + sys.argv[1:]

rows = subprocess.check_output(args).split(b'\x00')[1::2]

seen_commits = set([row.split(b'\x01')[0].decode() for row in rows])

print("digraph G {")
for row in rows:
    columns = row.split(b'\x01')
    commit = columns[0].decode()
    label = columns[1].decode()
    parents = columns[2].decode().split(' ')
    print('"{}" [label="{}"];'.format(commit, label))
    for parent in parents:
        if parent == "":
            continue
        if not parent in seen_commits:
            continue
        print('"{}" -> "{}"'.format(commit, parent))
print("}")
```

If you put that file on your `$PATH` as `git-log-dot` and `chmod +x git-log-dot`, `git` will automatically run it if you type `git log-dot`. (It's a legacy holdover from when `git` was distributed as separate scripts, `git-checkout`, `git-reset`, etc.)

You'll also need Graphviz. On macOS I installed it with `brew install graphviz`; on Ubuntu I believe you can install it with `sudo apt-get graphviz`.

You can generate a PNG file using `git log-dot` like so:

```
git log-dot | dot -Tpng -o graph.png
```

(In the sample above, I also used `-Grankdir=LR` to make the graph horizontal, but the default vertical orientation is pretty good, too.)

Comment: All of these are just minor tweaks: (1) you're not actually using `re`, hence don't need it. (2) I'd recommend `git rev-list --parents` instead of `git log --pretty=format...`, though you'll need to add `HEAD` as a default and do your own rev-id abbreviating (but that's probably a good idea as you can determine the minimum value for unique abbrevs). The splitting will have to go by newlines first, then spaces, to get commits plus their parent set. (3) Might be cool to have the python code run dot directly and then open a window or browser... :-)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there a way to convince git log to generate the simpler graph I'd prefer? There's an old gist from 2013 proposing fixing this ("Let me specify which branches sink to the left"; there are other interesting ideas there, too), but I see no progress on that.

No.  (And as I said in the other question, in general this is kind of a hard problem—in fact, it's "NP hard" in general.  Git's log-drawing code is fairly cheat-y but swapping the parents around would probably do the trick *for this case*, but there are many other cases.)

> 2. Assuming git log can't do it naturally, is there another git commit graphing tool/library I can use to make a graph like this?

I don't know of any.  The `gitk` code that draws graphs is quite different from the `git log` code that draws graphs, but the problem—which generalizes to "draw a DAG with minimal crossings"—is just plain hard.  There are a lot of graph-drawing programs out there, though.  Reportedly, `dot` is pretty good.

See also [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing) and [this CS stackexchange question and answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14901).

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion to use `dot`! I wound up writing a Python script to use that in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42825588/54829).

Comment: @torek, re "*with minimal crossings*"; But it does not need to be minimal as 100% perfection isn't needed. It could just perform the algorithm based on some inputs from the user. Perfection is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2022, `git log` seems to work the same as before. But [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/) handles this beautifully:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming git log can't do it naturally, is there another git commit graphing tool/library I can use to make a graph like this?

The answer is that as far as i know you cant,
The only thing closed (**but not what you are asking**) is to use rebase (can be combined with `--onto`) whenever you want it so the log will be more flat.

But again - what you are asking is not possible due to the nature of git

The closest way to achieve what you are trying to do (but again not exactly what you want)

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline --boundary master...branch1
```

When trying to add `--topo-order` && `--no-walk` it does not help as well and has no effect.

#### To summerize:

As you figured out its not possible due to the nature of git.

> Assuming git log can't do it naturally, is there another git commit graphing tool/library I can use to make a graph like this?

I dont thing any other tool can do it since git will not "display" the different branch commit ( in your sample `9a0cb38`) on the same "line" with another branch